# Multi-valued INSERT for SQLite3 using PDO

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite, sql-insert

I am currently trying to use the multi-valued INSERT queries with SQLite3 and PDO.

I did some research and found that before SQLite version: 3.7.11 the multi-valued INSERT syntax was not supported. This has since (2012) changed.

My phpinfo() is informing me that:

```
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x   enabled
SQLite Library  3.7.7.1
```

Regardless of that, PDO doesn't seem to support using these kinds of INSERT queries using SQLite3.

My question is if there is any workaround this issue. I am working on an application that is compatible with both SQLite3 and MySQL. Seeing that both of them support multi-value inserts, I would hate to use two kinds of query and INSERT logic only because PDO is not up-to-date.

Some edits - adding code specifics:

Opening the DB connection:

```
public function useSQLite3($file)
{
    $dsn = "sqlite:$file";
    $this->dbService = new PDO ($dsn);
    $this->dbService->query('PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;');
    $this->dbService->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Method that handles the bulk insert to the DB:

```
public function bulkInsertLink(array $links)
{
    $insertRows = array();
    $placeholders = array();
    $j = 0;
    $i=0;
    foreach($links as $linkData) {
        $placeholders[$j] = '(';
        foreach($linkData as $columnData) {
            $placeholders[$j] .= '?,';
            $insertRows[$i] = $columnData;
            $i++;
        }
        $placeholders[$j] = rtrim($placeholders[$j], ',');
        $placeholders[$j] .= ')';
        $j++;
    }
    $query = 'INSERT INTO links (status, date, lang, group_ID, group_link_ID, link, sitemap_link) VALUES ';
    $query .= implode(',', $placeholders);
    $preparedQuery = $this->dbService->prepare($query);
    $preparedQuery->execute($insertRows);
}
```

$links is an array, where each element represents the information for one row to be inserted.

Comment: I wish I had come across this question a few hours ago. It would have saved me a lot of messing around. I am on a CentOS 6 system, and it was easy enough to use multiple `INSERT` statements.

Comment: I might also add that running multiple individual `INSERT` statements is painfully slow. The solution is to wrap these statements inside a transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PDO you can do multi values inserts like this:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO t VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?)');
$pdo->execute([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

But I'd personally prepared a single insert statement and executed it multiple times with different parameters.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I know how to make the multi-inserts. The problem is they do not work when PDO is using SQLite3, as I stated above. I was looking for a workaround to this.

Comment: Try this code, it works at my side: <?php


$pdo = new PDO('sqlite:mydb.sq3');
$pdo->exec('CREATE TABLE t (r1 int, r2 int)');

$statement = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO t VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?)');
$statement->execute([1, 2, 3, 4]);

foreach($pdo->query('SELECT * FROM t') as $row) {
    print_r($row);
};

Comment: Can you please tell me what SQLite3 PDO Driver are you using? I do something similar (will update the original message) but it doesn't seem to work for me)

Comment: PhpInfo states the following:

pdo_sqlite

PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
SQLite Library => 3.8.4.3

Comment: Thank you. Probably that's where the difference is. I will update my SQLite Library, though according to their website, version 3.7.7.1 is the version where multi-valued inserts were introduced.

Comment: I updated the SQLite3 library and the PDO driver and it fixed the problem. Thank you for your help.